# Sinon sandbox stub exported async function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I have below test code that stubs using Sinon sandbox

index.ts

```
export * from './init.actions';
```

init.actions.ts

```
import { ModuleAnswer } from '../models/choice';
import { init } from '../templates/config';
import { moduleQuestion } from '../questions';

export async function initActions(): Promise<any> {
    const moduleAnswer: ModuleAnswer = await moduleQuestion();

    return init(moduleAnswer.name);
}
```

init.actions.spec

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as questions from '../questions';
import { ModuleAnswer, ModuleValue } from '../models/choice';

describe('src/actions/init.actions', () => {
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
  let moduleQuestionStub: sinon.SinonStub;
  const mockAnswer: ModuleAnswer = {
    name: ModuleValue.CORE,
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should always call mandatory questions', async () => {
    moduleQuestionStub = sandbox.stub(questions, 'moduleQuestion').resolves(mockAnswer);
    await initActions();
    expect(moduleQuestionStub).to.be.called;
  });
});
```

.mocharc.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  diff: true,
  extension: ['ts'],
  package: './package.json',
  slow: 75,
  recursive: true,
  require: ['ts-node/register', 'test/mocha.require.ts'],
  reporter: 'spec',
  spec: 'src/**/*.spec.ts',
};
```

test/mocha.require.ts

```
require('sinon');
require('chai').use(require('sinon-chai'));
```

When I run with `console.log(moduleQuestionStub);` I get `[Function: functionStub]` in the result so the stub seems to be returned in the test itself

When I run test, the async function `moduleQuestion` is not stubbed. Why would be the case?

Comment: Firstly, the assertion statement is wrong. Change to `expect(moduleQuestionStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;`. Secondly, I didn't reproduce your issue. It works fine for me.

Comment: thanks. I've updated question with `.mocharc.js` and `test/mocha.require.ts`

Comment: not sure if that changes anything for reproducing the issue